# Mail functionality using OPA

Tags: email, opa

```
import stdlib.web.mail

from = {name="name" address={local="username" domain="gmail.com"}}
to = {name="name" address={local="username" domain="gmail.com"}}

r = Email.try_send(from, to, "Subject", {text = "This is Great!"})

server = Server.one_page_server("Mail", [], [], r)
```

the following error I'm getting

```
Error
File "mail.opa", line 6, characters 4-66, (6:4-6:66 | 166-228)
Function was found of type
Email.email, Email.email, string, Email.content -> Email.send_status but
application expects it to be of type
{ address: { domain: string; local: string } / 'c.b; name: string } / 'c.a,
{ address: { domain: string; local: string } / 'c.d; name: string } / 'c.c,
string, { text: string } / 'c.e -> 'a.
Types string and { none } / { some: string } are not compatible
Hint:
  Error occurred through field name.
```

Can anyone help me with Mail functionality in Opa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of problems with this code:

- Notice that in [`Email.email`](http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#email.opa.html/!/type_stdlib.web.mail.Email.email) type the `name` field is optional; so if you want to include it you should provide `some("name")`, not just `"name"`
- [`Server.one_page_server`](http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#server.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.web.server.Server.one_page_server) contains 2 arguments not 4.
- The last argument to `one_page_server` should be the `xhtml` of the page, whereas your `r` is the result of sending an email.

After those fixes your code could look something like this:

```
import stdlib.web.mail

from = {name=some("name") address={local="username" domain="gmail.com"}} : Email.email
to = {name=some("name") address={local="username" domain="gmail.com"}} : Email.email

page() =
  status = Email.try_send(from, to, "Subject", {text = "This is Great!"})
  <>Email sent</>

server = Server.one_page_server("Mail", page)
```

Comment: Hi akoprowski,
Can I schedule this mail functionality using opa?

Comment: Yes, you'll want to look at the [`Scheduler`](http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#scheduler.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.rpc.core.Scheduler).

Comment: Hi akoprowski,
Could you please help me How to cofigure MLstate-Twopenny and mattgu74-OpaCms applications in local?

Comment: I don't think those comments are a place for such a discussion :). You can open a new question or contact opalang by mail. Please note that Twopenny is VERY MUCH a work in progress and is currently on hold (as I'm busy with tons of other things). On the other hand OpaCms is by an author who's not at MLstate, so it may be better to contact him directly (via GitHub?).